# The method of reading an integral network PDU in Go

Tags: tcp, network-programming, go

I am developing a simple Go server program which receives client's request and process it. And the code is simplified as this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

const (
    pduLen = 32
)

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func main() {
    var buffer [4096]byte
    var count int

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", os.Args[1], os.Args[2]))
    checkError(err)

    for count < pduLen {
        n, err := conn.Read(buffer[count:])
        checkError(err)
        count += n
    }
    ......

}
```

I assume every request's length is `32` bytes (just an example). Because the `TCP` is a stream protocol, I need to use a loop to check whether an integral PDU is read:

```
for count < pduLen {
    n, err := conn.Read(buffer[count:])
    checkError(err)
    count += n
}
```

Is there any method to assure that an integral PDU is read? Personally, I think the loop code is a little ugly.

Comment: Would something like https://github.com/PreetamJinka/fickle/blob/5bd75baa183948345ef4c4854932f5889094f3f0/main_test.go#L13-L55 help? Ie: read the size, then read the all message in one `Read()` call

Comment: @VonC: A method I didn't know before, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer, to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the exact nature of the PDU you are receiving, but [this example](https://github.com/PreetamJinka/fickle/blob/5bd75baa183948345ef4c4854932f5889094f3f0/main_test.go#L13-L55) will look for the size, and then read everything (using [`io.ReadFul()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull)).

```
func read(conn net.Conn, key string) string {
  fmt.Fprintf(conn, GenerateCommand(OP_GET, key))
  if verify(conn) {
    var size uint16
    binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &size)
    b := make([]byte, size)
    // _, err := conn.Read(b)
    _, err := io.ReadFull(conn, b)
    if err == nil {
      return string(b)
    }
  }
  return ""
}

func verify(conn net.Conn) bool {
  b := make([]byte, 1)
  conn.Read(b)
  return b[0] == ERR_NO_ERROR
}
```

Used in:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":12345")
if err != nil {
  t.Error(err)
}
write(conn, "foo", "bar")
if !verify(conn) {
  t.Error("Bad write!")
}
if r := read(conn, "foo"); r != "bar" {
  t.Errorf("Bad read! Got %v", r)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my need is like a [ReadFull](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull), but the Read may return before reading size bytes. Right?

Comment: @NanXiao sure, you can adapt that code to use `ReadFull`. As for the size, it will always be read, since you "verify" the `conn` before attempting the read. That is what `verify()` is for.

Comment: But [net.Conn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) doesn't provide ReadFull, so I use the loop to get all the bytes.

Comment: @NanXiao you shouldn't: you should just get the bytes corresponding to the size you read at the beginning of `conn` stream.

Comment: Yes. But if the size is 30, it is possible to conn.Read only read 20 bytes. Right?

Comment: @NanXiao Read will read at most the number of bytes corresponding to its slice of bytes length. You will find its implementation in http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go. I don't know if it could read less. The point of my answer was: you should only need one call since you know the max size to expect (supposing the netFD Read call is an atomic one).

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindly help! I have written a simple code and done the test, The conn.Read() can read less.

Comment: @NanXiao so the size is the maximum size of the message, I suppose.

Comment: In my opinion, the size should be the integral PDU size. But the conn.Read() can read less, so maybe there is potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this issue in golang-nuts: [How to read an integral network PDU?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/cUvsGPg_mUo)
The code should be:

```
import "io"
......
pdu := make([]byte, pduLen)
io.ReadFull(conn, pdu)
```

Comment: Ok, I have modified the code in my answer to use `io.ReadFull()`